# Julia - Increase the size of an array, inserting a value at the beginning

Tags: arrays, julia

I have an array filled with some values. For example, after running the following code:

```
array = zeros(10)

for i in 1:10
   array[i] = 2*i + 1
end
```

the array looks like this:

```
10-element Array{Float64,1}:
  3.0
  5.0
  7.0
  9.0
 11.0
 13.0
 15.0
 17.0
 19.0
```

Now, I would like to add a new value in the first position to obtain something like this:

```
11-element Array{Float64,1}:
  1.0
  3.0
  5.0
  7.0
  9.0
 11.0
 13.0
 15.0
 17.0
 19.0
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It looks like you want to use [`pushfirst!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/index.html#Base.pushfirst!). This function modifies your array by inserting the new value(s) at the beginning:

```
julia> pushfirst!(array, 1)
11-element Array{Float64,1}:
  1.0
  3.0
  5.0
  7.0
  9.0
 11.0
 13.0
 15.0
 17.0
 19.0
 21.0
```

(N.B. in Julia 0.6 and earlier, `pushfirst!` is named  `unshift!`.)

You may also be interested in [`insert!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.insert!), which grows the collection by inserting a value at a specific index, and [`push!`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Base.push!) which add one or more values to the end of the collection.

See the [Deques](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/collections/#Dequeues) section of the documentation for many more useful functions for modifying collections.

Comment: `unshift!` has been renamed to `pushfirst!` on Julia-v0.7+

Comment: @Gnimuc: thank you - I wasn't aware of that. I'll add a note to the answer.